# Stack overflow error. using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

I am getting a stack over flow error in my program. I have a class with functions and properties that I need my partial class with the winform textboxes,checkboxes, etc to be able to access. When i build it is fine but I get a run time error. It points to the default constructor I have and am using in the winform, as to where Visual Studio claims the stack overflowed.
code:

```
public class TeamCreator:Form
    {
        //fields
        public string[] players=new string[12];
        public int[] points=new int[12];
        public int currentPlayerScore=0;
        public TeamCreator()//default constructor
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                this.players[i] = "";
                this.points[i] = 0;
            }

        }
        public TeamCreator(string[] teammates,int[] scores)//construct Team object with user input
        {
            this.players = teammates;
            this.points = scores;

        }
        public void setTeammates(string player,int index)//set players array
        {
            this.players[index] = player;
        }
        public void setPoints(int[] scoreList)//set points array
        {

                this.points = scoreList;
        }
        public void setPlayerScore(int playerScore,int playerNum)//sets a specific player's score
        {
            this.points[playerNum] = playerScore;

        }
        public int[] getPoints()//obtain array of points
        {
            int[] listOfPoints=new int[12];
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<11;i++)
            {
                listOfPoints[i]=this.points[i];
            }
            return listOfPoints;
        }
        public int totalPoints()//gets total points
        {
            int total=0;
            for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
            {
                total = this.points[i] + total;
            }
            return total;
        }
        public double meanPoints()//returns mean or average of total points
        {
            int total = this.totalPoints();
            int mean = total / 11;
            return mean;
        }
    }
}

              //winform code
              namespace TeamClass
{
    public partial class TeamClass:TeamCreator
    {
        public int indexOn = 0;
        public int current = 0;
        public TeamCreator newTeam = new TeamCreator();
        public TeamClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void playerInput_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)//adds players to players array and to list
        {
            string playerName = playerInput.Text;
            newTeam.setTeammates(playerName,this.indexOn);
            playerList.Items.Add(playerName);
            indexOn++;
        }
        TeamClass reopen = new TeamClass();
        private void restart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//allows user to restart program and make a new team
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            reopen.Show();

        }

        private void playerScoreDisplay_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//displays currently selected player when checked
        {
            string currentPlayerSelected = newTeam.players[current];
            MessageBox.Show("The current player selected is " + currentPlayerSelected + ".", "Current Player", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        private void playerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.current = playerList.SelectedIndex;


        }

        private void scoreInput_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)//gets player score
        {
            int currentScore;

            if (!Int32.TryParse(scoreInput.Text, out currentScore))
            {
                //tell user we can't parse the amount
                if (MessageBox.Show("Text did not parse to an integer, please try again", "Invalid Argument", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    // leave method if they don't want to try again
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //set the focus on the control so user can fix error
                    scoreInput.Focus();
                    //As a convenience select all text
                    scoreInput.SelectAll();
                    //exit method
                    return;
                }
            }

                newTeam.setPlayerScore(currentScore, current);


        }

        private void scoreInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)//makes sure numbers are being entered correctly for score
        {
            //only accept negative sign in first position
            if ((e.KeyChar == '-') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length == 0))
            {
                if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Contains("-"))
                    e.Handled = true;
            }
            //Only accept numbers, one decimal, one negative sign (-) and the backspace
            else if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == 0x08))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void totalPointsDisplay_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//displays total points when checked
        {
            int total=newTeam.totalPoints();
            MessageBox.Show("The total points for the team is " + total + ".", "Total Points", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        private void MeanPointsDisplay_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//displays mean points when checked
        { 
            double avg=newTeam.meanPoints();
            MessageBox.Show("The mean points for the team is " + avg + ".", "Mean Points", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }

    }
  }
```

Any help as to why I am getting this error and how to fix it would be much appreciated. I am kinda new to C# so am unsure of what the issue is.

Comment: Start by looking at the entire exception message, including stack-trace.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you may not be able to tell much from the exception. Instead of a helpful stack trace, you'll see a message like:

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

There are some ways around this if you do a search for "[stackoverflow exception stack trace](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=&ie=UTF-8&q=stackoverflowexception%20stack%20trace)".

The root issue is almost always recursion, though, so look for something calling itself, or two or three methods calling one another in a loop.

After quickly scanning your code, I found one almost immediately (there may be others too). Every time you instantiate a `TeamClass`, you're creating another instance, which creates another instance, and on and on.

```
public partial class TeamClass:TeamCreator
{
    ...
    TeamClass reopen = new TeamClass();
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I have my program working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you use the first 11 element in the array in all your code?
You define an array with 12 element but you always loop to the 11th element

```
 public string[] players=new string[12];
        public int[] points=new int[12];
        public int currentPlayerScore=0;
        public TeamCreator()//default constructor
        {
            here why you loop to 11 it suppose to be 12 or the array.Length
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                this.players[i] = "";
                this.points[i] = 0;
            }
```

Comment: I thought arrays went from 0 to one less than the size so i did from 0-11. If i'm not actually accessing all of them then would less than 12 or less than or equal to 11 fix that?

Comment: Yes i<=11 will fix that.  the size of the array is 12. and the condition is stop the loop if i is less than 11 so the last element in the array will be ignored.

Comment: one more thing the  
   TeamClass reopen = new TeamClass();  
should be a private in the method 
   private void restart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)